# How to import one image and set it as a UIIMageView. Then again with another UIIMageView?

Tags: swift, import, photo

So currently I have it setup where I can import an image and set it to a UIImageView. What i'm looking for is help with how to do it again. Ive tried a few things and haven't been able to get anything to actually work when I do it again. Ill add a photo example as well.

[Photo Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be6bx.png)

```
@IBAction func importImg(_ sender: Any) {
    //import image 1
    let picture = UIImagePickerController()
    picture.delegate = self
    picture.allowsEditing = false
    picture.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
    self.present(picture, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        picture1.image = image
    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: What is `picture1`?

Comment: That was just a placeholder for this example. Its an outlet for the UIIMageView

Comment: Are you getting the error in this line `picture1.image = image`?

Comment: As is it works fine, It lets me import the photo with out any errors or warnings. What im trying to do is keep that as is but then do it again. So tap a button import a picture and make it an UIImageView and then a second button that does the same thing but changes a second UIIMageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should ask if your first UIImageView is null, then load the image in that, if not, load the image in the second UIImageView.

```
if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

    if picture1.image == nil {
        picture1.image = image
    }else {
        picture2.image = image
    }
}
```